# Software solution to switch between computers using KVM switch

Tags: linux, windows-xp

I am using a Fling KVM switch (by Belkin), to connect 2 computers to my monitor
One computer is running XP and the other is running Linux.

My wireless switching mechanism has just gone the way of the saints
but Belkin has kindly supplied a software solution for this occurrence.  There is a small app called Fling (surprising) that allows me to switch from the XP machine to the Linux machine but nothing to switch back to the XP.  What I need to know is there a similar app for the Linux computer.  (NB I have tried Synergy but have no idea how to set it up - I've been told that synergy might work).

Answer (score 0):

Synergy does not yet (and at this rate might never) support KVM switching, it only does KM (keyboard and mouse) switching. You need at least two monitors, one on each computer for it to work.  That being said, if you do have two monitors, I would highly recommend using synergy as its much nicer than switching back and forth with a KVM and easier on your monitor.

I don't know of a software solution for Fling other than using something like VNC or other remote desktop protocol.